# Issue about huge query constructing huge object?

Tags: sql, design-patterns, software-design, legacy-code

I am working on a company's legacy project. There's a huge object which is constructed by a super long query. The query somehow looks like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM item i 
JOIN item_product prod on prod.item = i.id
LEFT JOIN product_shippingaddress ps on pa.product = prod.id
LEFT JOIN product_packageinfo pp on pp.product = prod.id
.
.
.
(80 lines of query)
WHERE item.id = @itemId
```

Which is a very long query involves many information about this product.

It constructs a huge object 'Item' which provides all kind of information of the item.
Taking the below example of how things works currently

```
int itemId = createItem(); //creates a record in item table
associateAddressToItem(item); // Add a shipping address to item
for(int productId in productsToAdd){
     addProduct(itemId); // insert info into item_product table
}
Item item = getItem(item); // This function invokes the huge query to collect information of a single item
for(Product product in item.products){
     UpdateItemPrice(product.Id,itemId);
     if (product.shippable()) 
     {
         addItemTax(itemId, product.Id); // add tax based on address and product attribute
     }
}
item = getItem(itemId); // calls the query to update information of the object
charge(item); //charge based on item's price and tax
```

This case invokes the function getItem twice. I don't think this is efficient at all, as long as it runs a huge query twice. However, I think it is needed currently because it needs to fetch information stored in database to update the object.

Is there a better way to handle this kind of situation? I feel it is not optimized but I can come up with a way to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I got your question right, here's what you do:

1. Creating an **empty** record in the table.
2. Filling in a table (item_product) with some data that you got.
3. Requesting that data **again**.
4. Updating the data.
5. Requesting that data **again**. x2
6. Updating the data. x2

And all of that is done querying the database.

What I suggest you to do:

1. Update the Item object in memory first, do as much calculation as you can without hitting the database.
2. Request an ID for the new record.
3. Update data in the database. **Once**.

Thus, most of the calculation is performed in memory without running long queries and requesting information you already have.